# How can i convert sql query into dax query

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I want to convert sql query into dax in power bi
my table is:-

```
channel  advertiser yr
colors  pepsi   2019
colors  apple   2019
colors  pepsi   2018
colors  google  2018
colors  lux     2019
```

I have tried sql query to find new advertiser:-

```
select advertiser from ads
where yr=2019 and advertiser not in --new ads
(select advertiser from ads
where yr=2018 )
```

I want to convert this query into dax, how can i do it?
I have tried this:

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE (VALUES(adv[advertiser]),
adv[channel]="colors",
adv[year]=2019 && VALUES(adv[advertiser]) 
not (VALUES(adv[advertiser]),
adv[year]=2018
))
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: CALCULATETABLE will create a totally new table (so you will have 2 different tables with adv), which gets calculated once when the data are loaded, I don't know which is your use-case, but maybe you just need a flag "New Adv" True/False in the advertiser table. What do you need to do with them? apply filters?

Comment: I need to find new advertiser in dax as I found in sql query.How can I write dax query similar to sql query.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a table with the "new" advertiser

```
EVALUATE
    CALCULATETABLE (
         VALUES(adv[advertiser])
        ,adv[channel]="colors"
        ,adv[year]=2019 
        , NOT adv[advertiser] IN CALCULATETABLE (
             VALUES(adv[advertiser])
            ,adv[year]=2018
        ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.. if we have multiple channels then how can I use group by in this?colors 2019 pepsi 
colors 2019 apple 
colors 2018 pepsi 
colors 2018 google 
sab 2018 coca 
sab 2019 apple 
sab 2018 kitkat 
sony 2018 kitkat 0
sony 2019 kitkat 0
sony 2018 coca 0
zee 2018 garlic 0
zee 2019 colgate 0
zee 2019 pepsi 0

Comment: GROUP BY means that you have to compute something... which is not the case of this query. There are functions like GROUPBY and SUMMARIZE to create aggregate tables. I have no clue about your use case but this is not what you usually do in DAX.

Comment: I have to find "new" advertiser channel wise .so how can I apply gruopby in above use case?